# Pulling current post/page data into header.php

Tags: loop

I want to pull some post/page specific data (author name, post ID, publish time, etc) into header.php to be used in meta tags. I am having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to do this. It is my understanding that I will need to create a loop within header.php to pull this data. How can I go about creating a loop for the current page/post if I don't yet know the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main query is actually processed before template is loaded, so data is available in header (if a little less convenient to use).

You don't actually *need* loop, [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) should give you ID for the queried object and *most* template tags have version that will return you results for that specific ID.

Loop would work just as well, but it's not very common to run it this early.

Comment: Ah good to know! I think I can get author name and some other info this way, but I can't find a template tag that shows publish date based on ID - is this possible?

Comment: @JoshMountain [`get_the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_date/) is one of those which (inconsistently) doesn't work for given ID, but you should get the idea how to, looking at its short source

Answer (score 1):

You obviously know the current page/post id. Because loading any template file, the query perform to fetch data of post, page, term or any other thing.

To add information into  tag, you should be using `wp_head` hook. Below is an example -

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_wp_head');
function wpse_wp_head(){
    // first make sure this is a single post/page
    if( !is_page() || !is_single() )
        return;

    // then get the post data
    $post = get_post();

    echo '<meta name="post_id" value="'. $post->ID .'" />';

    $author = get_user_option('display_name', $post->post_author );
    echo '<meta name="author" value="'. esc_attr( $author ) .'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to obtain a meta tag for the author on `header.php`:

```
  <?php
    if (is_singular()) {
      $post = get_post();
      $autor_fn = get_the_author_meta('first_name',$post->post_author);
      $autor_ln = get_the_author_meta('last_name',$post->post_author);
      if (!empty($autor_fn) && !empty($autor_ln)) {
  ?>
        <meta name="author" content="<?php echo "$autor_fn $autor_ln"; ?>">
  <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
```